# How to configure interceptor in Spring boot?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I have a spring boot application. where i am trying to below operation

**AuthenticateIntercepter.java**

This class is an Interceptor class in which I'mm trying to print the logs

```
package com.javamongo.java_mongo.configuration;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.web.method.HandlerMethod;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.HandlerInterceptor;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.HandlerInterceptorAdapter;

import com.javamongo.java_mongo.utils.JWTUtil;

@Component
public class AuthenticateIntercepter implements HandlerInterceptor {

    Logger log = org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass());

    @Override
    public void afterCompletion(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object object, Exception arg3)
            throws Exception {
        log.info("Request Completed!");
    }

    @Override
    public void postHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object object, ModelAndView model)
            throws Exception {
        log.info("Method executed");
    }

    @Override
    public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler)
            throws Exception {

        log.info("After request executed");

        return true;
    }

}
```

**WebMvcConfig.java**

This class is used to call the interceptor.

```
package com.javamongo.java_mongo.configuration;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.InterceptorRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurerAdapter;

@Configuration
public class WebMvcConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    AuthenticateIntercepter intercepter;

    @Override
    public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
        registry.addInterceptor(intercepter).addPathPatterns("/**");
    }
}
```

When i am calling a request i am getting below. but it is not an error

```
2018-11-09 12:24:34.805  INFO 3964 --- [nio-8090-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet' 
2018-11-09 12:24:34.805  INFO 3964 --- [nio-8090-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet': initialization started 
2018-11-09 12:24:34.865  INFO 3964 --- [nio-8090-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet': initialization completed in 59 ms
```

**POM.XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.javamongo</groupId>
    <artifactId>java_mongo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <name>java_mongo</name>
    <description>Spring Boot and mongodb</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.6.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-crypto</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.8.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.auth0</groupId>
            <artifactId>java-jwt</artifactId>
            <version>3.4.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

**My Problem:**

WebMvcConfig.java class not executing the AuthenticateIntercepter.java, by which I'm not getting the logs in console. So anyone tell me where i made mistake.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It works with the following:

**pom.xml** snippet:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>hello-world</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.6.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>


    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>junit</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>

        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>

    </build>
```

**HandlerInterceptor**:

```
@Component
public class MyHandlerInterceptor implements HandlerInterceptor {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyHandlerInterceptor.class);

    @Override
    public void afterCompletion(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object object, Exception arg3) throws Exception {
        LOGGER.info("~~~ After-Completion");
    }

    @Override
    public void postHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object object, ModelAndView model) throws Exception {
        LOGGER.info("~~~ Post-Handle");
    }

    @Override
    public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) throws Exception {

        LOGGER.info("~~~ Pre-Handle");
        return true;
    }
}
```

**Configuration**:

```
@Configuration
public class WebMvcConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

@Autowired
private MyHandlerInterceptor interceptor;

@Override
public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
    registry.addInterceptor(interceptor).addPathPatterns("/**");
}
}
```

**Sample Controller**:

```
@CrossOrigin
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
class HelloController {

    @GetMapping("/hello")
    public HelloMessage hello() {
        return new HelloMessage("Hello World!")
    }
}
```

**Results**: When I hit http://localhost:8080/api/hello

```
 2018-11-09 12:48:07.090  INFO 16992 : ~~~ Pre-Handle
 2018-11-09 12:48:07.233  INFO 16992 : ~~~ Post-Handle
 2018-11-09 12:48:07.233  INFO 16992 : ~~~ After-Completion
```

Comment: @SangramBadi it works just fine. I checked in code at this repository - https://github.com/arunkpatra/java_mongo. Just clone, and follow the instructions provided on teh README.md file.